# Is there a way to change the format of a date picked using Elementor's Form widget?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have a form with a date field and have set the field id like this:

```
[field id="date"]
```

The date field allows the user to use the date picker with Native HTML5 enabled.

**Actions After Submit**
Redirect -
I want the user to be redirected to a URL with their date input after the URL.

For example, the user selects 25/12/2021 from the date picker (25th December 2021). The field displays the picked date as DD/MM/YYYY (25/12/2021).

In the redirect settings, I have set the target URL to be "exampleurl/[field id="date"]
When the user completes the form, they are successfully redirected to "exampleurl/2021-12-25
However, the target URL is using YYYY/MM/DD instead of DD/MM/YYYY.

**What I have tried:**
I have tried resolving the issue using this solution but have no luck: https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/4435

I have tried changing the date format settings to "d-m-Y" here: /wp-admin/options-general.php

Can someone help me change the target URL from exampleurl/2021-12-25 to exampleurl/25-12-2021

Many Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to include your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can help. Simply linking to generic code on a third-party website is not enough for us to see what problem *you* are having. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what we need.

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in functions.php file of your theme (child theme).

```
<?php
add_action('wp_footer', function () {
       ?>
      <script>
      jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ){
            setTimeout( function(){
                  $('.flatpickr-input').each(function(){ flatpickr( $(this)[0] ).set('dateFormat', 'd/m/Y');});
            }, 1000 );
      });
      </script>
      <?php
});
```

Reference:
https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/4435#issuecomment-388606349